# Twitter bootstrap for the ipad landscape collapse bar

Tags: ipad, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am building a website using the twitter bootstrap base so that i can have a site that works on the ipad and also touch phone devices. 
So far my site looks great in all browsers, PC ipad and phone however ipad only works fine in portrait. When in portrait it has the lovely button in the corner which opens the expanding menu.

I want this to work on the landscape one too but can't seem to get it to work.

Could someone please advise me whereabouts in the CSS I need to look and also if possible what screen size I am looking for to make the collapse bar appear in landscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.
Just incase anyone else has the same problem:

iPad screen resolution is 1024 x 768 so in landscape mode it renders like a full web page.

There are ways to overcome this by detecting the device's browser user agent.

For more information see this:[Checking iPad user agent](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3888106/How-Can-I-Detect-the-iPhone--iPads-User-Agent.htm)